# Formatter works only once when used with rowObject

Tags: jqgrid

I have following jqGrid. The `'ActiveStatusText'` column is populated using `IsActive` column value of `rowObject`, using a formatter.

```js
{
    name: 'ActiveStatusText',
    width: 100,
    formatter: function (cellvalue, options, rowObject) {
             return rowObject.IsActive == true ? 'Active' : 'Retired';
    }

}
```

When button is clicked, the status display text (“'ActiveStatusText'” ) need to be updated.

1. When “Retire” button click complete, the status display should become “Retired” and the button text should be “Activate”. This works fine.
2. When “Activate” button click complete, the status display should become “Active” and the button text should be “Retire”. The status column does not get updated.

Why is the text change happen only first time? How to fix this?

[**Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/LijoCheeran/fp7mL659)

[image]

```js
$(document).ready(function () {

    function updateActiveStatus(rowid, isToActive) {

        alert(isToActive);

        $("#list").jqGrid('setCell', rowid, 'IsActive', isToActive);
        $("#list").jqGrid('getLocalRow', rowid).IsActive = isToActive;

        //Set display text
        $("#list").jqGrid('setCell', rowid, 'ActiveStatusText', isToActive);
    }


    var myData = [

        { "id": "35", "firstname": null, "codeval": "G", "note": "xx7866", "amount": "23", "IsActive": true },
        { "id": "73", "firstname": null, "codeval": "W", "note": "dd1047", "amount": "34", "IsActive": true },
        { "id": "75", "firstname": "LORA", "codeval": "H", "note": "rr7323", "amount": "56", "IsActive": true },
        { "id": "95", "firstname": "EST", "codeval": "M", "note": "gg574", "amount": "55", "IsActive": false }
        ],

        myGrid = $("#list");

    myGrid.jqGrid({
        datatype:'local',
        data: myData,
        colNames: ['ID', 'Note','Status', 'Action'],
        colModel:[
            {name:'id',width:70,align:'center',sorttype: 'int'},
            {name:'note',index:'note',width:100,sortable:false},
             {
                name: 'ActiveStatusText',
                width: 100,
                formatter: function (cellvalue, options, rowObject) {
                    return rowObject.IsActive == true ? 'Active' : 'Retired';
                }
            },
            {
                name: 'IsActive',
                width: 100,
                formatter: function (cellvalue, options, rowObject)                                                 {
                    if (cellvalue == true) {
                        return '<div><button class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default app-custom-button-retire" >' +
                           'Retire' +'</button></div>';
                    }
                    else {
                        return '<div><button class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default app-custom-button-activate" >' +
                                'Activate' +
                                '</button></div>';
                    }
                }
            }
        ],
        rowNum:10,
        pager: '#pager',
        gridview:true,
        ignoreCase:true,
        rownumbers:true,
        viewrecords: true,
        sortorder: 'desc',
        height: '100%',
        beforeSelectRow: function (rowid, e) {
            var $self = $(this),
                $td = $(e.target).closest("tr.jqgrow>td"),
                rowid = $td.parent().attr("id"),
                rowData = $self.jqGrid("getRowData", rowid),
                iCol = $td.length > 0 ? $td[0].cellIndex : -1,
                colModel = $self.jqGrid("getGridParam", "colModel");

            celValue = $self.jqGrid('getCell', rowid, 'FirstName');

            if (iCol >= 0 && colModel[iCol].name === "IsActive") {

                if ($(e.target).hasClass("app-custom-button-retire")) {
                    updateActiveStatus(rowid,false);
                    return false;
                }

                if ($(e.target).hasClass("app-custom-button-activate")) {

                    updateActiveStatus(rowid, true);
                    return false;
                }
            }


            //Avoid selection of row
            return false;
        }
    });


});
```

HTML

```html
<body>
    <table id="list"><tr><td/></tr></table>
    <div id="pager"></div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote you in the answer on your previous question, that jqGrid 4.6 is old (3 years old) and it contains many bugs, which are fixed later. I recommend you to upgrade jqGrid to the latest version of free jqGrid (it's 4.13.6 today). You code will start working.

In any way you can easy verify that the formatter will do called by `setCell`, but with the wrong parameter `rowObject`. jqGrid 4.6 uses DOM element of `<tr>` instead of real `rowObject` (see [the line](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/blob/v4.6.0/js/grid.base.js#L3646) of code, where `ind` is assigned [here](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/blob/v4.6.0/js/grid.base.js#L3642)). `rowObject.IsActive` will be `undefined` and the formatter of `ActiveStatusText` will return always `'Retired'`.

Only if you really can't migrate to free jqGrid, then you can use the following workaround:

```js
{
    name: 'ActiveStatusText',
    width: 100,
    formatter: function (cellvalue, options, rowObject) {
        var isActive = rowObject.IsActive;
        if (isActive === undefined) {
            // be called by setCell from buggy version of jqGrid
            isActive = $(this).jqGrid('getLocalRow', options.rowId).IsActive;
        }

        return isActive == true ? 'Active' : 'Retired';
    }
}
```

See the modified demo https://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/fp7mL659/2/, which uses the code. By the way I wrote you in the answer on your previous answer, that `setCell` changes the local data too. Thus the call `$("#list").jqGrid('getLocalRow', rowid).IsActive = isToActive;` after `$("#list").jqGrid('setCell', rowid, 'IsActive', isToActive);` is absolutely unneeded.

Comment: Convincing my manager seems to be difficult for moving to the free jqGrid version. Let me thank you first, for the willingness to share your knowledge about jqGrid. Why is no new version of jqGrid coming up? Is it due to increasing popularity of some other grids? What are the other grids that are used heavily these days?

Comment: @Lijo: 4.7 was **the last** version of jqGrid. The next version the produced developed by Tony Tomov (Trirand) was **commercial** product under *new name* "Guriddo jqGrid JS" (see [the post](http://www.trirand.com/blog/?p=1438)). See the prices and the license [here](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334).

Comment: @Lijo: Correspond to MIT license everybody are able to make a fork and continue own development. I made the fork of jqGrid 4.7 and started the development as [free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid) at the end of 2014. You can see on https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/compare/v4.6.0...master the exact difference between jqGrid 4.6.0 and the current code of free jqGrid. It's more as 1600 commits with really a lot of changes. I use the versions with 4.x.y conversion because I try to hold maximal compatibility to old 4.x versions of jqGrid.

Comment: @Lijo: You can see the description of new features in READMEs to all published versions, in [the wiki](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/wiki) and [here](https://free-jqgrid.github.io/getting-started/index.html). There are exist no full documentation of all new features, but I'm working on `free-jqgrid.d.ts`, which you find [here](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/blob/master/ts/free-jqgrid.d.ts), which can be used in TypeScript and which will describe all methods, events and options of free jqGrid.

Comment: Can you please specify which all cdn file references need to be included, for trying out the free jqGrid?

Comment: @Lijo: See [the wiki](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/wiki/Access-free-jqGrid-from-different-CDNs). `grid.locale-en.js` is unneeded if you use US-English locale. You need include `https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/free-jqgrid/4.13.6/css/ui.jqgrid.min.css` and `https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/free-jqgrid/4.13.6/js/jquery.jqgrid.min.js` only.

Comment: @Lijo: You used just wrong URL`https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/free-jqgrid/4.13.6/js??/jquery.jqgrid.min.j??s`  in the second demo. The fixed demo with the same code is https://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/zyf9n784/4/. The same code could be a little shorter in case of usage free jqGrid: https://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/zyf9n784/6/